# object name is bind as prefix in input control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

currently I am working in asp.net mvc view

I create form using below code.

```
@{
    T4.Models.Order o = new T4.Models.Order();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Default5", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => o.CustomerID, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>o.CustomerID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => o.CustomerID)
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
}
```

this code render perfectly but problem is it render with prefix of object's name.

**show below html code**

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerID field is required." id="o_CustomerID" name="o.CustomerID" type="text" value="">
```

you can see this html input control has **id="o_CustomerID"**.I want that it only render with **id="CustomerID"**.

I does not know why it takes object name as prefix.

please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the model in your view? Unclear what your trying to do here. If you want a form for editing `Order`, then your view needs to be `@model Order`

Answer (score 0):

No need to initialize object of T4.Models.Order class.

```
@{
    T4.Models.Order o = new T4.Models.Order();
}
```

Replace above code to:
@model T4.Models.Order

Then simple use:

```
<div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=> model.CustomerID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: i have to do with create the object because my model class already decorate with  @@model IEnumerable<T4.Models.Order>

Comment: If your model is already decorated with your IEnumerator class then use it directly.

Comment: please tell me how can i use with IEnumerator

Comment: I can tell you a small example IEnumerable<T4.Model.Order>